# Error when tkinter is destroyed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have made a snakes and ladders program and want the game to end once someone has won. I did research and found out if I use the code below it should force close the program.

```
diceWindow = Tk()

diceWindow.destroy()
```

The window does close but errors come up:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/Python /snakes and ladders.py", line 172, in numup
    whosgoisit()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/Python /snakes and ladders.py", line 176, in whosgoisit
    btnRoll = Button(diceWindow, text="Roll", command=rolltwosDice(), width =20)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2209, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2139, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command:  application has been destroyed.
```

How can I force close the program without the error coming up.

The code mentioned in the error is for the dice:

```
def numup():
    global count
    count += 1
    whosgoisit()

def whosgoisit():
    if (count % 2 == 0): #even
        btnRoll = Button(diceWindow, text="Roll", command=rolltwosDice(), width =20)
    else: #odd
        btnRoll = Button(diceWindow, text="Roll", command=rollonesDice(), width =20)

btnRoll = Button(diceWindow, text="Roll", width=20, command=numup)
btnRoll.grid(row=100,column=0,columnspan=10)
```

Comment: the error says it. Somewhere in your code must tried to invoke a button after you called `diceWindow.destroy()`

Comment: Are you sure the only place you are calling `whosgoisit` is from `numup` ?

Comment: The code above is the only bit that invokes a button and is the only place where whosgoisit is called.